# Добавить php код в шаблон .tpl

Tags: php

Не могу добавить php код в следующий шаблон. Как выйти из положения?

```
<div class="feedback-item">
<div class="item-inner clearfix">
        <div class="item-tools">
            <span class="item-author">{%AUTHOR%}</span>
            <span class="item-date">{%DATEQUESTION%}</span>
        </div>
        <div class="item-content clearfix">
            <div class="item-image">
                <a title="Отзыв от {%AUTHOR%}" href="/images/feedback/{%ANSWER%}.jpg" onclick="return hs.expand(this, config1 )"><img alt="Отзыв от {%AUTHOR%}" src="/images/feedback/{%ANSWER%}-sm.jpg"></a></div>
            <div class="item-text">{%QUESTION%}</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

UPD: Как сюда ввести новую переменную вида %PEREM% со значениями из БД?

Comment: Это twig? Если да, то мне кажется, что это невозможно. НО... в twig есть все необходимое, чтобы обработать любую переменную (массив, объект): http://twig.sensiolabs.org/documentation

Comment: Вся беда в том, что сам никак не разберусь, что это. Админка WebDom

Comment: @kirill mazurik, это не твиг

Comment: @Batyabest, в контроллер добавить, например. Значения в шаблон выводятся с котнтроллера.

Comment: А где контроллер найти?